# Creating desktop application that tracks time spent in different programs

Tags: java, .net, windows, desktop-application, software-design

i'm a CS student and for my semester project I want to make an app that tracks user time in different programs, prepares reports with time spent user spent "productive" and how much procrastinating, shows how much time user spends doing some tasks ans stuff like that.

I know there is a bunch of applications like that but I feel completely clueless about where should i start and how i might make it work.

I wasn't able to find any tutorials or articles on the subject, so i try to ask somebody for help. Maybe somebody could hint me in right direction or give a link to related tutorial.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not a code writing service, or for finding libraries or other offsite resources. Questions should be about code that is not working, not asking us to create/advise on the creation of code.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Okay, sorry.
Not asking someone to write code for me, just thought maybe someone has related experience and could hint me on what I should look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone out there having same question.

In C# there's actually a class Process (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)
It has a lot of useful methods like getProcess() which returns all processes currently running on a computer.

And about this class there are articles like (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/understanding-process-in-C-Sharp/) with in-depth explanation how everything works and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, granted, you're a "budding" programmer. As is the case for any huge task (your app doesn't sound like a college class calculator program), the first step is to break the problem into pieces. Did you pay attention to the class you took (I'm sure its part of your CS class curriculum) regarding requirements and design? So, I think the first step would be to put coding aside for the moment, sit down with paper and pencil, and jot down some `program requirements` for your `user time tracking app`. What are the expected `inputs` to your app? What `transformations` will your app make to this `inputs`? Finally, what `outputs` should your app produce?

A good way of making your brain think about these topics is to write [use cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case)  or [user stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story). Once you understand what your app needs to do, you can think about a `design` (e.g., [Steps to design](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25074&seqNum=4)) and then writing the code. One major decision during design time will be a high level decision regarding how you'll approach the design. Two (of many) primary approaches being `procedural` (a.k.a. `functional`) or `object-oriented`.

For an app of this size, you have a lot to do before writing the first line of code, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I understand that I have whole bunch of UML diagrams, user stories and other planning to do before starting coding.
Bur i have to actually understand how it should work and what I need to make it work to do that, hence I'm asking how it's might be done theoretically

Comment: It seems to me that the basis of your program would be the ability to monitor program run times. For a `Windows` machine, I guess I'd start by reading up on `PerfMon` (Performance Monitor). For example, https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_perfmon.htm

Comment: In other words, take advantage of the functionality (measuring, logging, etc) already available. Your perhaps app would use the outputs produced by PerfMon